# Splunk authentication through web application

Tags: splunk

I am trying to integrate splunk inside my web app (javascript, Aria templates) using iframe. The app already has a login module so I need to use the same credentials (say username: admin, password: pass) to login to splunk. For testing, I have created the same user and password in splunk also.

I have no Idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Why using iframe?

Comment: I do not want to use a SDK since it will require me to write the entire UI. Instead I wanted to use the feature rich splunk webapp, hence iframe.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Splunk into your own web app, add the SplunkJS Stack libraries to it:

1. Download SplunkJS Stack.
2. Extract the files.
3. Copy the contents of the SplunkJS_Stack/static/ directory to your web site's static directory.

You can visit http://dev.splunk.com/view/webframework-developapps/SP-CAAAEW5 and https://answers.splunk.com/topics/iframe.html for further and more detailed usage and questions.